# infinite {0,1} vector with no constant arithmetic progressions

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Is it possible to construct an infinite vector of 0 and 1, i.e. an element of $x\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z}$, with the following properties:

-there is a $K>0$ such that for every $\ell\in\mathbb Z$, $(x_i)_{i=\ell}^{\ell+K}$ contains both a 0 and a 1;

-$x$ does not contain any arithmetic progression of 0 or 1: i.e. for every $p,q\in\mathbb N,$ $(x_{p+nq})_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ contains both a 0 and a 1?

Comment: This is easy; just do something similar to what antkam did for your other question. Also, why did you delete your two unanswered questions about the random bijection? I found them interesting